# Wrong newline character over serial port (CR instead of LF)

Tags: linux, serial-port, newlines

I'm trying to talk to a device using a usb-to-serial converter on linux. Drivers are working, the device exists at /dev/ttyUSB0.

There is a strange problem (checked with a null-modem cable to another computer): Whatever program I use to connect to the device (putty, minicom, screen), they all send a CR (\r) on enter. I (and my device) expect a LF (\n) on enter.

When I use the console to send a command - it sends a LF:

```
# echo Hello World > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Results in "Hello World\n".
I also wrote the classic c hello world program (printf("Hello, world!\n");) and redirected the output to /dev/ttyUSB0 - also gives me a "Hello world\n" on the other end of the line.

But all other terminal programs send a \r on enter.

What's going on here?

Comment: Standard TTY protocol is to sent a CR from the keyboard when the user has finished typing and for the computer to echo LF when it's ready for the next line.

Comment: Check the current settings of your tty with `stty -a`. Use `stty -ocrnl` to change the output behaviour of CR being translated to LF.

Comment: I tried all kind of options, nothing changed the behaviour. Really strange. Anyway it's an old problem that I currently do not care for (anymore).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess by “enter” you mean the <kbd>Return</kbd> key of your keyboard,
probably labeled <kbd>↵</kbd>.

**Short answer:**

The reason why putty, minicom and screen send CR when you hit
<kbd>Return</kbd> is because the <kbd>Return</kbd> key actually means
“Carriage return” (CR).

The reason why `echo` and `printf("Hello, world!\n");` send LF is
because they end their output with `\n`, which means LF. Note that these
programs do not hit a <kbd>Return</kbd> key: they do not even touch a
keyboard.

**Long answer:**

Back in the seventies, we were transitioning from [tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)s to CRT-based
computer terminals. Early terminals had keyboards with separate keys for
CR and LF. On the DEC [VT05](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT05), these were labeled, quite appropriately,
<kbd>CR</kbd> and <kbd>LF</kbd>. On the [VT50](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT50) and [VT100](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT100) series,
they were labeled <kbd>RETURN</kbd> and <kbd>LINE FEED</kbd>. Later
models dropped the <kbd>LINE FEED</kbd> key and we ended up with
<kbd>Return</kbd> and no key for LF. Nowadays, these bulky terminals
have been replaced by terminal emulators such as rxvt or gnome-terminal.
However, as the name implies, a terminal emulator's job is… to emulate a
terminal! Thus, the situation hasn't changed that much: the
<kbd>Return</kbd> key still stands for CR, just as it did in 1975.

On the other hand, Unix standardized on using LF as the end-of-line
indicator. Both in text files and in user-space programs, lines of text
are always terminated by LF. This begs the question: how do we then
interact with a Unix system using a terminal that makes sending LF a lot
harder than sending CR? The answer is… it depends on what specific
program we are interacting with.

When we interact with a “naive” program, or rather a program that
doesn't bother to handle the terminal, the in-kernel terminal driver is
in “canonical” (or “cooked”) mode. In this mode, it translates the CR
characters coming from the terminal to LF, and the outgoing LFs to CR+LF
sequences. These translations can be seen as the `icrnl` and `onlcr`
flags in the output of `stty -a`.

Some programs prefer to handle the terminal themselves: they [instruct
the terminal driver](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) to refrain from doing character
conversions (they set it to “raw” mode) and handle these conversions
themselves. Most often this is done within a library such as
[readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) or [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Bash is one of those programs (it uses
readline) but, thankfully, it resets the terminal to cooked mode before
`exec()`-ing other programs.

Now, imagine you want to talk to some sort of device that speaks text on
a serial port. You go to your attic and grab your old [VT420](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT420) that has
been collecting dust there for almost 30 years. You hook it to your
device using a cross-over (“null-modem”) cable, and voilà! Your device
has a terminal! How cool is that? Hopefully, this device has been
designed to play nicely with a classic terminal: it expects
CR-terminated messages. If it expected LF instead, then you would have
to end your lines by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, as the VT420
has no dedicated <kbd>LINE FEED</kbd> key.

If you don't own any of these lovely vintage terminals, you can use
instead an emulated one such as gnome-terminal or [cool-retro-term](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term).
You connect it to your device using a communication program such as
minicom, or [picocom](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom), and a USB-to-serial converter. In their default
configuration, these communication programs do not mess with your data
stream: they configure the tty driver in raw mode (on both ends), and
they forward the bytes faithfully between your emulated terminal and
your device, just like the null-modem cable would do with your VT420.
But unlike a null-modem cable, picocom can be configured to translate
the line endings on the fly if needed.

Comment: Really nice & elaborate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

If using `picocom`, it's a matter of mapping the serial output from `CR` to `CR+LF`.

Example:

```
picocom /dev/ttyS0 --baud 19200 --omap crcrlf --echo
```

Actually able to send commands to the device now!

Comment: I was looking for a general explanation / solution. As I mentioned in the question, I'm able to write my own program in C that works (does send a LF). Anyway, your answer might be helpful for someone else ...

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `crlf` instead of `crcrlf` so that it converts `\r` to `\n`, not `\r\n`.

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure you have set the ttyUSBx port in raw mode. Otherwise there can be some character replacements e.g. `\r` with `\n` and vice versa on receiver side.

Comment: For anyone from an internet search, to do this, just add `raw` in the settings. e.g. `stty -F /dev/USB0 115200 raw`

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.

Comment: The answer is, simply, wrong.

Answer (score 1):

***TLDR: you can't;*** *Screen will override any options set via `stty` when it starts. It doesn't support the `ocrnl/onlcr/icrnl/inlcr` options required to configure carriage return vs. newline. It opens the terminal device in exclusive mode, so you can't use stty to change these options after screen starts. This is true for Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU), 05-Feb-20.*

#### Long form:

I've run into this same issue, and have searched through several related questions and answers across the stack exchange universe. I'm forced to conclude that **You can't get screen to send Line Feed (LF; `\n`) instead of Carriage Return (CR; `\r`)**, at least not without changing something in the source and recompiling.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/714078/wrong-newline-character-over-serial-port-cr-instead-of-lf) asks how to send LF instead of CR from screen. It doesn't have an answer yet. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/773822/603560)
 is wrong (`stty -F /dev/YOURSERIALDEVICE YOURBAUDRATE raw` won't change how screen configures the tty). [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1492749/603560) suggests using picocom, but doesn't answer the question of how to get screen to send the correct newline character. It does, however, work:

```bsh
picocom /dev/YOURSERIALDEVICE --baud YOURBAUDRATE --omap crcrlf --echo
# (press Control+a Control+x to exit)
```

There are hints for how one might address this for *screen* in the stty man page. Screen forwards the comma-delimited list of options after the tty file to stty, so some of these options might help:

```bsh
> man stty
# (output abridged..)
Input settings:
       [-]icrnl    translate carriage return to newline
       [-]inlcr    translate newline to carriage return
Output settings:
       [-]ocrnl    translate carriage return to newline
       [-]onlcr    translate newline to carriage return-newline
       [-]onlret   newline performs a carriage return
```

However, setting both input and output to replace `\r` with `\n`, ensuring that `\n` isn't replaced by `\r`, and ensuring that `onlret` is not set ... doesn't make a difference,

```bsh
screen /dev/YOURSERIALDEVICE YOURBAUDRATE,ocrnl,-onlcr,icrnl,-inlcr,-onlret
```

behaves the same as before. I'm not sure why screen doesn't seem to apply the options. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523901/900749) to a vaguely similar question suggests using stty to change the options.

```bsh
> stty -F /dev/YOURSERIALDEVICE YOURBAUDRATE ocrnl -onlcr icrnl -inlcr -onlret
> screen /dev/YOURSERIALDEVICE
```

This does nothing, because screen resets any configuration performed by stty when it starts. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779405/900749) claims that one can run stty *after* screen starts, but when I do this I get the error `Device or resource busy`.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238787/134513) also addresses the issue with CR/LF in screen. It refers to the [Window Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Types) section of screen's online documentation.

- **"an exclusive open is attempted on the node to mark the connection line as busy"** -- so we shouldn't be able to change the tty options after starting screen.
- Only `baud_rate`, `cs8/cs7` (number of bits per byte), `ixon/off`, and `istrip` are documented options. This probably means that ocrnl etc. aren't recognized/supported by screen.

**In summary:** The question of how to get screen to send LF (`\n`) instead of CR (`\r`) has been asked several times on various stack-exchange sites. None of the provided answers work, and a thorough reading of the documentation suggests that it's not possible at this time.

Comment: The question and problem ist NOT about screen. That was just mentioned as an example program which exhibits the problem – just like many other programs do. Your answer seems kinda close to the point, but actually misses it completely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but it has frustrated me for long enough. As @MRule [mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/1680093/616930), this issue doesn't seem to be solved with any of the given answers here.
A similar issue on Unix & Linux exchange had a better [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275764). So, this might help in case anyone lands here in the future.

[`python-pyserial`](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) comes with its `miniterm` which seems to do "the right thing" with cr and lf. Should be available in your distro's repository or on pypi.

```
pyserial-miniterm /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
echo -e "Hello World\n" > /dev/ttyUSBx
```

where x={0,1,...n}

The `-e` is used to send (i.e. interpretation of) special characters

Check help on Ubuntu 18.04 terminal:

```
~$ help echo

echo: echo [-neE] [arg ...]
    Write arguments to the standard output.
    
    Display the ARGs, separated by a single space character and followed by a
    newline, on the standard output.
    
    Options:
      -n    do not append a newline
      -e    enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
      -E    explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
(...)
```

Comment: Hello JohnBR, thanks for taking your time to suggest a solution, but you missed the point. Please read my question (and other peoples questions) carefully. "echo" does exactly what I expect (send LF aka '\n'), so there's no need to add any option here. All the other programs are "misbehaving", not echo. Usually I'd give a downvote in this case, but since you're a new contributor I don't.